# How to remove quotes from req.params.id when sending query

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to send data from a table to the client depending on the table the user selects.

```
/** GET ALL VAULES IN A PARTICULAR TABLE */
serve.get('/data/:id', (req, res)=>{
  dbConn.query(
    'SELECT * FROM ?',
    [req.params.id],
    (error, rows)=>{
      if(!error){
        //when there is no error
        res.send(rows);
      }else{
        //when there is an error
        res.send(error);
      }
    });//END dbConn
});//END SERVE
```

From the above, I'm expecting all the data in the table, but I keep getting the error below when I do something like "localhost:1234/data/alert"

```
{
    "code": "ER_PARSE_ERROR",
    "errno": 1064,
    "sqlMessage": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''alert'' at line 1",
    "sqlState": "42000",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "SELECT * FROM 'alert'"
}
```

From this I do realize that the error is because the table name is quoted; how do I fix this error?

Comment: Unless node is somehow different and I doubt it. You cannot have a table name as a parameter.

Comment: I'm beginning to believe so myself...
D'you reckon there's a solution or hack to this?
@RiggsFolly

Comment: Simple text concatenation. But that may lead to an [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) vector

Comment: Can I ask WHY a user is deciding upon a table to query? It is not a very normal concept

Comment: Beats me honestly...
It's a request from my boss...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways -

1. Concatenate the query string.

```
/** GET ALL VAULES IN A PARTICULAR TABLE */
serve.get('/data/:id', (req, res)=>{
  dbConn.query(
    'SELECT * FROM '+ req.params.id,
    (error, rows)=>{
      if(!error){
        //when there is no error
        res.send(rows);
      }else{
        //when there is an error
        res.send(error);
      }
    });//END dbConn
});//END SERVE
```

Edit- as mentioned in comments by @RiggsFolly, query concatenation could lead to an Sql Injection Attack. Keep that in mind.

2. If you are using `mysql`module then use built in method

```
/** GET ALL VAULES IN A PARTICULAR TABLE */
serve.get('/data/:id', (req, res)=>{
  dbConn.query(
    'SELECT * FROM ??',
    [req.params.id],
    (error, rows)=>{
      if(!error){
        //when there is no error
        res.send(rows);
      }else{
        //when there is an error
        res.send(error);
      }
    });//END dbConn
});//
```

`?` is for values and `??` is for escaping query identifiers.

Comment: Glad to hear that:)